# onreadystatechange IE all versions browser mode change

Tags: javascript

I'm doing something like jQuery `document.ready()` function. Here's my code:

```
var ready = function(callBack){
    if(document.readyState=="interactive"||document.readyState=="complete"){
        console.log("already : "+document.readyState);
        callBack();
    }else{
        document.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log("change : "+document.readyState);
            if(document.readyState=="interactive"){
                callBack();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And using like:

```
ready(function(){
    alert(document.querySelector(".try").innerHTML);
});
```

My problem is it working on all browsers. But when I change browser mode on Internet Explorers console page `document.readyState` gives result `"interactive"`. So I was thinking it's a cache issue firstly but when this happened I can't use my elements in page. Can anyone help or have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution:

```
var ready = function(callBack){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",callBack,false);
    }else if(document.attachEvent){
        try{
            var isFrame = window.frameElement != null;
        }catch(e){

        }
        if(document.documentElement.doScroll&&!isFrame){
            function tryScroll(){
                try{
                    document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
                    callBack();
                }catch(e){
                    setTimeout(tryScroll,10);
                }
            }
            tryScroll();
        }
        if(isFrame){
            document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
                if (document.readyState==="complete"){
                    callBack();
                }
            });
        }
    }   
}
```